# DoublyLinkedList getData problems

Tags: java, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I am having trouble with my doublyLinkedList getData method. The getData method is inside my Iterator, yet its acting like that method does not exist.

```
    if (USE_LINKED_LIST)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.linked_list.size(); i++)
        {
            Movable current = this.linked_list.getData();
            current.paint(graphics);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.array.size(); i++)
        {
            Movable current = this.array.get(i);
            current.paint(graphics);
        }
    }
```

As you can see in this code segment, I am trying to call this.linked_list.getData() however it is acting like there is no such method.

```
 public AnyType getData()
    {
        //Gets the data inside the currentNode
        return currentNode.getData();
    }
```

This is however the getData method inside my Iterator. I am having the same getData() problem in this next code segment

```
if (USE_LINKED_LIST)
    {
        for(int i =0; i < this.linked_list.size(); i++ )
        {
            Movable current = this.linked_list.getData();
            current.move(frame_rate_duration);

            if(current.dead())
            {
                this.linked_list.remove(current);
                i--;
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.array.size(); i++)
        {
            Movable current = this.array.get(i);
            current.move(frame_rate_duration); // move for 1/100 of a second simulated time

            if (current.dead())
            {
                this.array.remove(i);
                i--; // go back one spot so we don't skip an item
            }
        }
    }
```

I am just wondering if i need to change my for loop?? or if i need to change the getData() method.

Comment: Too much of your code is taken out of context to be able to tell what is going on. If you don't know why you can use the method in some places and not in others, you may want to review [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: _"it is acting like there is no such method"_ -- if that were the case you would get errors at compile time.  What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: What is this.linked_list declared as?  I am wondering if your linked list class that exposes the getData method inherits an interface of yours that does not have said method, and you are referring to the linked list via the interface?

Comment: You say *"The getData method is inside my Iterator"*, but by the looks, *you're not using an iterator*, but the list itself. At least that's what `this.linked_list` looks like to me. I'd expect something like `Iterator it = this.linked_list.iterator()`, followed by the usual calls of `it.hasNext()`, `it.next()` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What is `this.linked_list` declared as?  It is hard to tell from your description but I am wondering if your linked list class that exposes the `getData` method inherits an interface of yours that does not have said method, and you are referring to the linked list via this interface?

If that is the case then you will need to cast your linked_list to the appropriate type, or preferably I assume, declare it directly as your type / subclass.

This, of course, is all based on your comment "it is acting like there is no such method" meaning that your are receiving a compiler error indicating there is no such method in your linked list class.

Other possibilities:

- Your class shares a name with another (perhaps default) class and the wrong one is imported.
- Your IDE is not correctly refreshing / building all of your classes (so an old version without your `getData` method is being used)